# Bash script return to menu if status code inside of a while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm doing a bash script to check cryptocurrency prices, and it updates in a while loop like this:

[Crypto prices real time updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsRcX.png)

[While loop function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaXiH.png)

The problem is that due to being an infinite loop, I couldnt think of a way of returning to the main menu, but today seeing **timeout** command I've tried doing this so that I can return to the main menu if there's a key pressed:

```
echo -e "\n\n\t${blue} Press a key to return to the Main Menu..${end}"; 
        timeout 1 bash -c "read -s -n 1 key"
        if [ $(echo $?) -eq "0" ]; then
            mainMenu    
        fi
```

In linux command line it is working (if a key is pressed before the timeout, status code equals 0, else, status code equals 124) but for some reason using this structure into the while loop doesnt work.

[Structure into the while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nJE6.png)

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- that is, include enough of the `while` loop to show the problem, but remove things that aren't specifically relevant (like the currency price checking). Also, please post the code as text (in code format), not as images. And include a better description of the problem -- "doesnt work" is not specific enough to he useful.

Comment: The screenshot you give for the while loop at the end of your answer doesn't actually show the condition for while loop (i.e., the `while <some condition here>` is missing from the screenshot).

Comment: Please do not put code as images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Stop using `echo` that much. Don't `var=$(echo $var2)`. Just `var=$var2`... `$(echo $?)` is just `$?`, that's a useless `echo`. Please do not post pictures of text. Please post the text as text into your question. `some reason using this structure into the while loop doesnt` Are you expecting `key` variable to be set? It is set inside a subprocess, not affecting current process. Please check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using too much of bash :P `read` itself also has a timeout option `-t`. The line below says "if read doesn't exit correctly, do not show content `DATA`. If you do not react within one second, the exit status will be `142`.

```sh
read -t 1 -p "Enter something: " DATA
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] || echo $DATA
```

You can translate this to:

```sh
read -t 1 -p "Enter something: " DATA
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] || mainMenu
```

If you want to exit the while loop entirely, use `break` instead.

ps. small note on the if statement:

```sh
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    mainMenu    
fi
```